# the bit operation in c++

Tags: c++, bitwise-operators

I have a question about bit operation in c++,

there is a set of code:

```
#define INDEX(SRC, DEST) ((U16)SRC | (DEST << 8))
```

what does this `(U16)SRC | (DEST << 8)` means?

Comment: http://dpx.googlecode.com/svn-history/r4/trunk/libdpx/BaseTypeConverter.h

Comment: SRC is typecast to (i guess) unsigned int (16bits wide), DEST is shifted 8 bits to the left (same as multiplying DEST by 256) and then the result undergoes an OR operation, so it's like `( SRC | ( DEST * 256  ) )`

Comment: It's not a very solid macro though. Calling this with INDEX(a,b&c) results in very interesting results if you don't anticipate what order the operators get executed in.

Comment: By the way, never write macros like this. It can give unexpected results if either argument is an expression (e.g `INDEX(s1+s2,d1+d2)`). In C++, you should nearly always use an inline function for something like this; if for some reason you have to use a macro, then make sure you put parentheses around every appearance of the macro arguments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would guess U16 is also a macro somewhere in the code and it probably designates a 16-bit unsigned integer type(which I deduce from the abbreviation). SRC and DST are the two arguments to the macro expansion the code is defining and (U16)SRC | (DEST << 8) would mean that DEST gets bit shifted 8 bits to the left and then logical or-ed to SRC. Probably the code depends that both SRC and DEST are 8-bit values and this code creates a bit mask that is the result of the appending of the 8-bits of DEST to the 8-bits of SRC.

For instance if (in binary) DEST is 10010101 and SRC is 00001111 then the result is 1001010100001111.

Answer (score 4):

- `(U16)SRC` casts `SRC` to be of type `U16`.
- `(DEST << 8)` does a bitwise shift left of 8 bits.
- The `|` operator performs bitwise `OR`.

Answer (score 1):

It casts `SRC` to a `U16` type and performs a bitwise OR with `DEST` after it has been left-shifted by (8) positions.

Answer (score 0):

With the code you showed it is a lot of guessing: sure, it looks as if `U16` is a macro for `unsigned short` or `uint16_t`. If you want to find out, what the define expands to include the definition of the the macro and invoke the macro in a simple test program:

```
#include "whatever-defines-INDEX.h"

INDEX(10, 1)
```

Then invoke the compiler with the `-E`option (or the `/E` option if `-E` isn't available and you are using Windows): this sends the result of running the preprocessor to the standard output.